# Couldn't connect mongodb 2.4 with GoLang

Tags: mongodb, go

I couln't connect mongodb with golang.

telnet mongoHost 27017 it is okey

ping mongoHost it is okey

MongoHost is my private host not docker

Mongodb version : 2.4.3

MongoDriver: 1.3.2

Go version: go version go1.14.1 darwin/amd64

Operation System: Mac

Here is my connection code

```
clientOptions := &options.ClientOptions{}
clientOptions.SetServerSelectionTimeout(4 * time.Second)
clientOptions.SetDirect(true)
clientOptions.SetAppName("tests")
clientOptions.SetHosts([]string{"mongoHost:27017"})
clientOptions.SetReadPreference(readpref.Secondary())
client, err := mongo.NewClient(clientOptions)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
err = client.Connect(ctx)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

I changed timeout but It doesn't changed connection every time I got this error:

```
2020/04/12 14:06:19 server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: Unknown, Servers: [{ Addr: mongoHost:27017, Type: Standalone, State: Connected, Average RTT: 13849652 }, ] }
```

Comment: Can you connect if you use `clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://mongoHost:27017")`?

Comment: I tried connectionString but  not working

Comment: And what error do you get?

Comment: context deadline exceeded.

Comment: I added ping 
err = client.Ping(ctx, readpref.Primary())

 if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)

 }

Comment: Where you getting context from?

Comment: I think this is mongo driver bug. I connect docker mongo db which versiyon is 3.4 but production 2.4

Answer (score 0):

The client settings that you've set are contradictory. Either you're establishing a direct connection to a single replica set member, or establishing a connection to a replica set with read preference secondary. I would suggest to change it to something simple:

```golang
client, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://mongoHost:27017/?replicaSet=FOOBAR"))
```

See also [mongo-driver: Connect](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo?tab=doc#Connect) to see various code examples on how to connect.

> Mongodb version : 2.4.3

Please upgrade your MongoDB server version. The least compatible version for MongoDB Go driver version is MongoDB server version 2.6. See [MongoDB Compatibility chart](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference#go-driver-compatibility) for more information.

MongoDB v2.4 was released in 2013 (7 years ago), currently version 4.2. I would strongly recommend to upgrade, please see [Upgrade MongoDB to v2.6](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/2.6-upgrade/) then follow through the upgrades until the most recent versions that satisfy your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Go mongo driver doesn't support Mongo 2.4
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/GODRIVER-1571